# What is the no. of distinct binary trees possible with n labeled nodes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

It was given in this [link](https://gatecse.in/number-of-binary-trees-possible-with-n-nodes/) that:

> For a binary tree with n nodes, the no. of edges is n−1. So, this
> problem can be reduced to the no. of ways in which we can make n−1
> edges from n vertices.   An edge can be made either as a left child of
> a node or as a right child.  Hence, for n nodes, we have 2n
> possibilities for the first edge, 2n−1 for the second edge and so on.
> Thus, for n−1 edges, the total no. of ways
>
> = 2n×(2n−1)×(2n−2)×….×(2n–(n–2))
>
> = 2n×(2n−1)×(2n−2)×….×(n+2)
>
> =(2n)!/(n+1)!

I did understand that the first edge can have 2n possibilities because for each node there is left and right child options. I cannot figure out how second edge can have 2n-1 possibilities?

What are the possibilities for second edge when n=3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how second edge can have 2n-1 possibilities?

There were 2n possibilities until you added the first edge.

After adding the first edge one poiibility is occupied and only 2n-1 possibilities left.

After the second edge only 2n-2 possibilites left and so on

For n=3 there are 6!/4!=30 variants. Just check: there are 5 configurations, every has 6 permutations:

```
/\    /     /     \     \
     /      \     /      \
```

Comment: This answer does not explain what exactly the remaining possibilities are. It uses a different logic to come to the same number, but that does not really help to understand the logic presented in the question.

Comment: The answer (as well as OP's cited reference) skips over the question of how to consistently integrate the `n` partial trees of a vertex with 0, 1, or 2 incident edges into a single tree while guaranteeing that the construction bijectively maps onto all possible binary tree structures. What am I missing here ?